# Ubuntu changing shell on me

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

This Ubuntu machine is showing errors when I start a new terminal.
The problem is this:

When bash completion is sourced (`. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`) the shell taking place is not `bash` and some variable definitions with lists `local words=()` is failing (because only `bash` understands lists).

My solution was to explicitly call with `bash /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, but I'd like to know why another shell is being called when I open terminal. I thought that, since bash is my default, that it would also be used during sourcing.

I've done a `echo $0` just before calling the bash-completion file and the output is `bash`.

What would cause bash not to be used for sourcing?

Addressing questions from comments:

This happens when I start a new console, which means that the kernel will start a new terminal window, calling the `~/.profile`, which in its turn do a `. "$HOME/.bashrc"`, which will in its turn source the bash completion (`. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`)

I don't have a `~/.bash_completion` file.

I can't put the `echo "$0"` to inside of the bash_completion because it will fail and not be executed.

My `.bashrc` and `.profile` are the default ones that come with Ubuntu. I don't have a `.bash_profile`. You can find them in your local Ubuntu 14.04 under `/etc/skel/`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain i) where the source command is. What file? When is it run? ii) if this is a script, show us the script.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` before you source that file. Do you see anything odd?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_completion` file?

Comment: If you want to change your default shell, use the `chsh`  command like so : `chsh -s bash`. Also, note that sometimes the terminal emulator you use can start a new shell by its own. For instance, in `konsole`, my default profile starts `bash` by default (I therefore use `bash` locally) but I had to use `chsh` so that my shell would be `bash` also when I use `ssh`.

Comment: @user43791 my chsh points to /bin/bash. That is the default. I just checked and it hasn't changed. I don't want to change my default shell, I am trying to find out why would Ubuntu decide to change it to sh instead of bash.

Comment: Actually, if your script executes `bash` with the header `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` (first line of your script), `bash` will be posix-compliant and additional features might be missing (no arrays in `sh` mode). Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: @user43791 I don't think this is the problem. I just checked `/etc/skel/.profile` and it doesn't have a she bang. Also, it doesn't make sense that I have to define the shell on a process started by the core, since the chsh also defines the default shell.

Comment: If you run `bash` from an already-open terminal, do you have the same problem? What if you run `bash --norc`? and `bash --login`? When you write “new console”, do you actually mean a text mode console (tty), or do you mean a terminal emulator in the GUI, and if so which one? In a problematic shell, what is the output of `echo $SHELL; ps $$`? What is the complete content of your `.profile`, your `.bash_profile` and your `.bashrc`?

Comment: I'm not an expert but there're some questions. Why didn't you put echo $0 inside(not before) the /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion itself? What error did you get from running  local words=()?

Comment: hi @林果皞. Adding the echo to inside of the bash completion doesn't work when I source it because I get an error and the bash completion is not executed. The error is bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 310: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 310: `    local cword words=()'

Comment: Hi @Gilles, I''ll update my question with the 3 files.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos But can't you removed the portion of code which might cause the syntax error, and then put echo $0 inside the file ?

Comment: @林果皞, removing all `()` which cause errors and adding the `echo $0` returns `bash`

Comment: @AlexandreSantos referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-in-linux-between-source-and-sh, the main difference is subshell and the env.  So you can try to print env for both bash VS dot and then diff.

Comment: You're making some assumptions.  Please paste the actual error message in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem wasn't the shell or chsh or anything exotic. It was a stupid alias on local. Someone thought it was a good idea to create an alias that displays the local ip address, and named it "local", so the line

```
local cword words=()
```

was failing not because the shell couldn't handle arrays. It failed because the alias was expanding and the `()` didn't make sense there.